# Count from mongo of the same query with limit 1 (Node.js)

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

My query is :

```
 event.find({
    id:{$get:id},
    num:"5"
}).limit(1)
```

but i also do the same query and get count result (from the same query) 
so 1 result is the last one with limit 1 and second is the count without the limit

how do i do that in MongoDB ?

one option i was think about is do the same query but without limit , for example, get 2000 results and count in node.js code.

my node code:

```
result = await this.collection.find({
    'val':obj.val,
    'id' : {$lt: id}
}).sort({id:-1}).limit(1).project({_id:0})  

let count  = await result.count()
```

but count always return 1 (because the count should ignore the id option)
is it possible?

example:

request is name=yy and id =3

```
1-  { id :3 , name:yy  },
2 - {id : 2 , name:yy}
```

another example

result will be : row 2 (3 greater than 2) . with count = 2

```
  1-  { id :3 , name:yy  },
    2 - {id : 2 , name:xx}
```

result will be : []  with count = 1 . (the same query without id < id)

Comment: Do you want `count` and `limit` with a single query?

Comment: yes or from node.js code .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below aggregation using [**`$facet`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/)

```
result = await this.collection.aggregate([
  { "$facet": {
    "count": [
      { "$match": { "id": { "$lte": id }}},
      { "$count": "count" }
    ],
    "data": [
      { "$match": { "val": obj.val, "id" : id }},
      { "$sort": { "id": -1 }},
      { "$limit": 1 },
      { "$project": { "_id": 0 }}
    ]
  }}
]) 

result = result[0].data
const count  = result[0].count
```

Comment: How can I prevent from the id for the count calculation

Comment: Can you explain bit more. I didn't get you

Comment: it's working but the count return the whole table. 
i need the count doing the same query without the match of id < last id (in the question i put id=id but i meant to id < last id , i updated the question